# Write sitemap using PHP

Tags: php, sitemap

I have a function that assigns my sitemap content to a php variable, I need to open the "sitemap.xml" file from http://www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml and replace the content with the the variable's content, how can I do this?

Comment: Is that file a remote / local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: I tried both `file_put_contents('sitemap.xml' , $output);` and `file_put_contents('/sitemap.xml' , $output);` but it didn't worked, my "sitemap.xml" file is in the root directory of the site, the same of "index.php"... what could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have write permissions on sitemap.xml?

Comment: I was wrong, I made ​​a stupid mistake, very thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local file you [could simply do](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file' , $dataVar);
```

This will replace the content with the new content.

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.

Comment: I tried both `file_put_contents('sitemap.xml' , $output);` and `file_put_contents('/sitemap.xml' , $output);` but it didn't worked, my "sitemap.xml" file is in the root directory of the site, the same of "index.php"... what could be the problem?

Comment: I was wrong, I made ​​a stupid mistake, very thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

write a function that takes the php variable and converts it to xml using `SimpleXMLElement` and than save the content of is using `$xml->asXML("sitemap.xml");` where `$xml` is the root element of your xml

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
file_put_contents('sitemap.xml' , $output);
```

here sitemap.xml is a output file and `$output` is output of xml dynamic content.